# How to create slider with decimal values using html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a slider showing decimal values like 0.0 to 0.1 using html or html5.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 15):

Add `step="0.1"` in your input range tag like this: `<input type="range" min="0.1" max="1.0" step="0.1" value="1">` Example:

```js
document.getElementById("scale").oninput = function() {
  document.getElementById("spanscale").innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0.1" max="3.0" step="0.1" value="1" id="scale">Scale:<text id="spanscale" style="inline">1</text>
```

If you want to show a decimal place `.0` on integer numbers you can add this piece of code in the value output: `Number(this.value).toFixed(1)`

```js
document.getElementById("scale").oninput = function() {
  document.getElementById("spanscale").innerHTML = Number(this.value).toFixed(1);
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0.1" max="3.0" step="0.1" value="1.0" id="scale">Scale:<text id="spanscale" style="inline">1.0</text>
```

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you want an input field that the user can click arrows to increment/decrement a value in steps of 0.1. If that's the case, you want to use an HTML5 `numeric input` element:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5" />
```

Find out more here at [HTML5 Goodies](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/whats-new-in-html5-forms-handling-numeric-inputs-using-the-number-and-range-input-types.html#fbid=ZAMIEsAeGgA).

Comment: This does not create a slider

Answer (score 1):

As you precise HTML5, then you can use the new input type range :

```
<input type="range" name="things" min="1" max="10">
```

[image]

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/qNXWq/)

Be aware that [it doesn't work on IE9-](http://caniuse.com/#search=range),though.

Comment: Does HTML5 have a decimal slider instead of a string slider? http://jsfiddle.net/crajpn0d/

Answer (score 0):

For setting this dynamically using **JavaScript**:

```
document.getElementById("my_slider").setAttribute("step", "0.1");
```